$(SolutionDir) is blank for a Visual Studio 2022 C# project when using it in any Preferences text box
I am following a tutorial online using PInvoke in order to call into a C++ native .dll.  All things seem to be working properly, until I get to a point where I need to set the Base Output Dir for the build artifacts in the Properties page of the C# project.
As you can see here, the path doesn't show $SolutionDir, it is blank
When I try to use it in Post Build Events, it is also telling me that this is an undefined value.
At the end of the build there is an undefined showing
I can use pretty much any other macro such as $(Configuration) $(Platform), etc, but $(SolutionDir) just will not work.  Has this been removed as supported recently?
My Visual Studio version is
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (2) (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.11.4
I tried using this macro first in the Base Output Directory, and then when that didn't work, I tried to use it in a script within the Events section and tried doing a copy ($SolutionDir)\file command to the output directory I want to use.  But no matter where I try to use $(SolutionDir), it does not work.
I would expect to the solution dir to expand to the directory of the solution's directory path.
Interestingly, this path DOES seem to work in the C++ project properties page:
Using $(SolutionDir) in C++ project
When I build the C++ project, this path is working:
The output path is getting resolved correctly here to the path of my solution file.

I am grabbing the popcorn...

Similar, but not quite the same, question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67758687/why-solutiondir-is-undefined-in-dotnet-cli

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753078/whats-purpose-of-solutiondir-element-in-csproj-file

Have you tried exiting visual studio, deleting the .vs directory, deleting all bin\ and all obj\ directories, then relaunching visual studio?

Why do you need to set the Base Output Dir for the build artifacts in the Properties page of the C# project?  Does the default not work if you leave it blank?

For those interested in a workaround, I found the following way to do this.  If you edit your C# .proj file and use it as an item to copy to the output path afterwards this appears to work.
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="..\NativeLibrary\bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\NativeLibrary.dll">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>

Thanks to the provider for this answer: Are there any better ways to copy a native dll to the bin folder?
But still, it would be good to know why SolutionDir can't be accessed in any build events.
